# Android L Notification.Builder.setVisibility() not resolved by Android Studio

Tags: android, notifications, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm having trouble using android.app.Notification.Builder.setVisibility() from Android L. I've updated Android Studio to Beta, downloaded the L SDK, and set my compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 20. But Android Studio still can't resolve the setVisibility method.

(Edit: I updated the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion based on comments below, and updated my support libraries from 20.+ to 21.+ )

Without the setVisibility() line my code compiles and runs. I get the same errors if I try NotificationCompat.Builder instead.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 'android-L'  // was 20
  buildToolsVersion '20'
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 13
    targetSdkVersion 'L'  // was 20
  ...
  ...

compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'


import android.app.Notification;

...

 noti = new Notification.Builder(InfoPanel.getContext())
                    .setContentTitle(notiTitle)
                    .setContentText("text")
                    .setSmallIcon(notifyIcon)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .addAction(firstActionIcon, firstActionText, firstActionPI)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.optionsmenuicon, InfoPanel.getContext().getString(R.string.options), piOptions)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.exit, InfoPanel.getContext().getString(R.string.remove), piExitNotification)
                    .setContentIntent(upperPendingIntent)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setVisibility(VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                    .build() ;
```

I get the IDE errors "Cannot resolve method 'setVisibility(?)'" and "Cannot resolve symbol 'VISIBILITY_PUBLIC'"

Edit: The first Gradle build error "Cannot resolve method 'setVisibility(?)'" is gone after I updated my compileSdkVersion, but it still shows as red in the IDE. The second error is still in both places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setVisibility` is **not** in API level 20 - it is API level `L`, which is currently in preview. Make sure you are targeting the right API level and include the revision `21-rc1` version of the support library (which forces you to target `L` only).

Comment: Which support library? I'm using these:     
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:20.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'

Comment: Both `support-v13` and `appcompat-v7` both contain `support-v4` so you can remove that line entirely. The others need to be `:21.+` to use `L` preview features.

Comment: Ok now I've got 
    compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
    targetSdkVersion 'L'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'

I still have the Gradle build error: 
    Error:(175, 40) error: cannot find symbol variable VISIBILITY_PUBLIC

And the same red IDE messages.

Comment: I also needed to change to NotificationCompat.Builder to fix the red error on setVisibility and NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC to fix the red error on the constant. Now it works.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Why is the 21-rc1 support library necessary? Shouldn't targeting "L" be enough?